# Rabbi Dovid Oppenheim's introduction to the Ein Yaakov- Where is it?

Tags: jewish-books, agada-stories-legends

In the commentary *[Eitz Yosef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enoch_Zundel_ben_Joseph)* to Gemara Berachos daf 3a, on the words "ve'ha kamashma lan..." he references an introduction to the Ein Yaakov by [Rabbi Dovid Oppenheim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Oppenheim_(rabbi)). I looked around and could not find this introduction. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the introduction on HebrewBooksorg here: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47602&st=&pgnum=12